# Does Linux MONO support ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mono

I'm not finding any clear answer on this. On the [Compatibility](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) page, they say:

> Everything in .NET 4.7 except WPF, WWF, and with limited WCF and
>   limited ASP.NET async stack

What about .NET Core 2.2? Is it possible to run it on MONO or not?

I'm glad .NET Core framework is becoming more mature; but unfortunately it doesn't support legacy WebForms, and MONO's support for Core is unclear, so they don't mix well.

Answer (score 3):

[Mono 5.4 implements netstandard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). Since ASP.NET Core 2.x runs on netstandard 2.0, Mono 5.4 also does support ASP.NET Core 2.x.

Note that starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, the framework will only run on .NET Core. That means that if you want to stick to Mono, you will have to stick with ASP.NET Core 2.x.

Since ASP.NET Core 2.2 is not a long time support (LTS) release, which means that it will run out of support not too long after 3.0 releases, I would recommend you to stay on ASP.NET Core 2.1 if you want to run it on Mono.

That being said, there isn’t really a reason for you to run on Mono there. You can just use .NET Core properly. If you need Mono around for other WebForms projects, then you can just do that for those projects. But for ASP.NET Core, you can just choose the .NET Core runtime. Because in the end, ASP.NET Core and WebForms will not mix, even if you run both on Mono.